# Trying to make a quadrature amplitude modulation - Having problems in the quadrature output

Tags: amplitude-modulation, quadrature

Here is the transmitter circuit:

[image]

This is the receiver circuit:

[image]

I think everything is fine in the AM transmitter but not in the receiver circuit.

In the 'in phase' part of the receiver circuit, I would say everything is ok:

[image]

[image]

In the 'quadrature part' of the receiver circuit the Q signal seems to be very low:

[image]

[image]

Is this supposed to happen? The I mixer in the transmitter circuit has a 1 microsecond period while the 90 degrees shifted mixer has a time delay of 0.0025m seconds in relation to the first one.

This is source signal and the output of the AM transmitter:

[image]

Vout2 signal is ok but it's almost all thanks to the in phase component, the quadrature part is doing pretty much nothing.

Comment: Just by way of simplification, you can generate something similar using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixx66.png) rather than all that other stuff for the transmitter section. 3 lines of Spice is a *lot* less work and allows you to divide and conquer.

Comment: You may want to combine the **I** and **Q** by summing their squares (and taking the square root.) Standard Pythagorean stuff. So long as you keep them 90 degrees apart, you can play with their phase relative to the carrier. And while your filters are right on the nose, frequency-wise, that fact may not be desired and will cause the signal to be attenuated at their output.

Comment: @jonk according to what the other user said the carrier is in phase with the I mixer so the Q signal is low. If i change the phase of the I mixer (and also the Q to make them 90 degrees apart) the Q signal will get higher?

Comment: Assume the carrier is at 0 degrees. The I and Q need to be 90 degrees apart, but if does not matter where they are with respect to the carrier. So one can be 110 degrees and the other 200 degrees. Or 90 degrees and 180 degrees. Depending on where they are one will have more signal, the other less. But put together with Pythagorean, their combined magnitude will be the same regardless of their relationship to the carrier.

Comment: @jonk In this case because Q is so little, wouldn't adding Q and I do the same thing as applying the sqrt and adding their square?

Comment: In ***this*** case you have Q arranged to produce almost nothing, I gather. Rotate **Q** by 25 degrees (and **I** also by 25 degrees) and **Q** will show up as something and **I** will diminish somewhat. What you are missing, perhaps, is that your receiver will have ***no idea*** about how **I** and **Q** relate to the phase of the carrier. It's totally random. What you want is for that fact to ***not matter***. If you arrange things right it won't matter and in fact it can vary moment to moment, drifting around all over the place and the results will be solid no matter what. That's the point.

Comment: I have an appt to rush off to and no time to write much. So I'll throw out an LTspice run to show what I mean in an answer. I may come back (hours from now) to answer questions, deal with objections, and/or delete my answer as useless. But it will be later when any of that gets done. I need to leave here in less than 30 minutes. So this is all I can type up in short order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the LTspice run:

[image]

There are a few lines in the upper left hand corner to set up the  \$100\:\text{kHz}\$ carrier and the \$1\:\text{kHz}\$ signal (V97 and V98.) B99 is the AM generated with less than 100% modulation, made to look as similar as I felt like to what I saw you posting up. V99 and V98 are rails for the LT1800's, which are what I used here for opamps. Those lines of text make up the transmitter.

Explicitly showing are the receiver parts. Va and Vb are the carrier frequency, 90 degrees apart, but where I allow a parameter called **PH** to rotate them around, a bit. You can see the .STEP line in the lower left corner which sets the phase shift to 6 different values. Vc and Vd are the **I** and **Q** products. These will vary around depending upon **PH**. Their outputs are fed to copies of your low pass filters (except that I reduced the resistor values by a factor of 10 as you don't need to cut corners as closely as you did. I wanted an output from them that wasn't attenuated so much.

Their outputs are then combined by B3 on the schematic, using the Pythagorean theorem. (There are circuits for this, too.)

I plotted the output of B3 (Ve and a red color) along with the original signal (Vy, which is defined over in the upper left-hand corner's text there.)

You can easily see that no matter how I rotate the **I** and **Q** phases with respect to the original modulation carrier the output is always the same.

Let's dump out the **I** and **Q** now to see what they are doing:

[image]

Now you can see that they are not always looking the same. They vary. And if I'd selected a relative phase to the carrier that would zero one of them out, then you would have seen a straight line output from that filter. But it doesn't matter! Combining the **I** and **Q** correctly always recovers the right result.

One last adjustment to select a different set of **I** and **Q** angles relative to the carrier and to add (on top) the transmitted carrier with less than 100% modulation:

[image]

You can play these games all day. The results are the same.

I have to take off now.

Added: Just got back to add the modulation to the last screen shot. I'd forgotten to add it here, before, as I didn't have time then to remember to add it.

Comment: Nicely done. Let me emphasize that the **unknown phase** of the received carrier sinewave forces us to use the complex I&Q arrangement. That final RMS sqrt{I^2+Q^2} is difficult to do with analog circuits. In a non-critical case, I've used the larger of: abs(I)+0.5*abs(Q) or abs(Q)+0.5*(abs(I)). Its rude & crude

Answer (score 1):

The Q channel outputs nothing if the radio signal happens to be  in phase with the LO-input of the I channel mixer. The I channel outputs nothing if the radio signal happens to be in-phase with the LO-input of the Q channel mixer.

The adder is a fatal misconception. You should have a circuit which makes geometric sum i.e. the squareroot of the sum of squares. Only it extracts properly the original signal.

Learn for ex. this: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/radio-frequency-demodulation/understanding-quadrature-demodulation/

Comment: So the radio channel is in phase with the LO input of the I channel mixer? How can i see/know that?